# Error 503 -service unavailable on wamp

Tags: wamp, wampserver, http-status-code-503

I installed `Wamp` on my system and it worked perfectly on `Windows 8`. I later installed `Ubuntu` alongside it and since then i am getting a 503 service error on my localhost. 
I tried removing ubuntu and reinstalling windows 8 but it did not help either.
Can someone tell me how to rectify the error?

Comment: check the log and find out what is specially cauing the issue

Comment: i found the solution to my problem. Actually i was using a proxy for local addresses too which i have now disabled and its working fine  now

Answer (score 0):

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service
If the Start resume service menu item is Green then Apache is running.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> MySQL -> Service
If the Start resume service menu item is Green then MySQL is running.

If Apache is the service that is not running it is normally, but not always, because something else has captured port 80.

Now do,
Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80
This will launch a command window and display some information about what, if anything is using port 80.

Whatever it is should be re-configured to not use port 80 or uninstalled if you are not using it.

If port 80 is not the problem look for errors in the appropriate error log ( use the wamp manager menus to view the error logs )

If these do not exists or show no errors then also check the Windows Event Viewer
Start -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer
And look in the 'Windows Logs' -> Application' section accessed from the menu on the left of the dialog for error messages from Apache and or MySQL.

How to Configure SKYPE so it does not require port 80 or 443

Run SKYPE
then using the menus do this:
Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection
Un-Check the checkbox next to 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections'
Now restart SKYPE for these changes to take effect.

How to Configure Team Viewer so it does not require port 80 or 443
Run TV
Extras -> Options -> Advanced -> Press the Advanced Button -> Advanced Network Connections
Check the checkbox saying [ Dont use incomming port 80 (recommended for web servers only ) ]

If the problem is not obvious then post the errors here